# Dispatching event on disconnectedCallback

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

Is there a way to dispatch an event when an element is removed? I tried the following:

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener('child-removed', this._handleChildRemoved);
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <my-child-element></my-child-element>
    `;
  }

  _handleChildRemoved() {
    console.log('child removed!');
  }
}

class MyChildElement extends LitElement {
  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();

    console.log('removed');

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('child-removed', {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`
      <p>Child</p>
      <button @click=${this._handleClick}>X</button>
    `;
  }

  _handleClick() {
    this.remove();
  }
}
```

`console.log('removed');` is called but `console.log('child removed');` is not called.

Answer (score 1):

For full details see: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/678

In this use-case: your  `_handleClick` method does the remove,
so put the dispatchEvent there, before you call `this.remove()`.

The `disconnectedCallback` is for clean-up,
the element itself is already removed and can't perform DOM actions,
as you can see with: `console.log("removed",this.innerHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a way to engineer this behaviour using event emitters, I believe the recommended pattern for this behaviour is to pass a function from the parent to the child component as a prop. This function can remove the child. So the source of truth is the parent.